# Developed an RTP program vs. Developed a RTP program

Tags: grammar

See title. Which one is correct?

For reference, in case it matters, RTP is an acronym that stands for Real-time Transport Protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you should use *a* or *an* depends on how you pronounce RTP. If you pronounce it "are tee pee", then *an* is the correct article. If you pronounce it "real-time transport protocol" (which I suspect nobody does), then *a* is the correct article. If you pronounce it *ritip* (again, nobody does, but some acronyms are pronounced in equally weird ways), then *a* is the correct article